# Flutter- "extendBody: true" does absolutely nothing. I want to extend the body behind the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I want my body to occupy the entire screen. I've tried using `extendBody: true` but it seems to do absolutely nothing. Here's the sample code along with a screenshot-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
      ),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I'm running a pixel 3xl avd with android R

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the app run in full-screen by adding `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` to the `build` of `MyApp` class:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return MaterialApp(
...
```

2. Set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` for the `Scaffold` to remove the extra space behind the navigation bar:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.orange,
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Result:

[image: res]

Comment: when I do this the body moves down from the status bar and I'm left with a black status bar. Like so-  [Imgur](https://imgur.com/uNTAKUj)

Comment: Can you put the edited code in your question? @Ashwin

Comment: yes I've done it now. It's exactly as you've instructed.

Comment: This is weird. I'm using the exact same code and it works. Have you tried making a new avd? @Ashwin

Comment: I found the problem. Go to ***Settings -> System -> Advanced -> Developer options -> Display cutout*** and select **Device default**. @Ashwin

Comment: The cutout is already set to Device default. I've tried it on 2 other devices- Nexus 6 and Pixel 3a XL. They work as intended on both. But again, they're notchless devices. I tried reinstalling the Pixel 3 XL avd but the results are the same. Black notification bar. Really weird.